# how to form a change of basis matrix with eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization, matrix-decomposition

So I have found $3$ eigenvectors: $E(1): (2,-1,1), E(2): (1,0,0), (0,0,1)$

Where $E(i)$ is just the eigenvalue. So how do I determine my change of basis matrix? In my textbook they just say the change of basis matrix is:

$(1,0,0)^T, (0,0,1)^T, (2,-1,1)^T$ but i want to know how do they determine the order of the columns?

Answer (score 0):

order of the columns determines the order if the diagonal matrix. for example,
if $U = \pmatrix{2 & 1 & 0\\-1&0&0\\1&0&1},$ then the diagonal matrix will be $D= \pmatrix{1&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&2}.$ if you permute the columns of, you will permute the diagonal in the same way. in other words calling the columns of the matrix $U$ as $u_1, u_2, u_3$ you are writing the three equations $Au_1 = u_1, Au_2 = 2u_2, Au_3 = u_3$ in matrix form as $$AU = UD$$ the permutations of the columns can also be written as $AUP = UPP^TDP$ for any permeation matrix $P.$

suppose we switch the first and the third columns of $U$ and obtain 
$U_1 = \pmatrix{0&1&2\\0&0&-1\\1&0&1}$ then the new diagonal matrix will be 
$D_1 = \pmatrix{2&0&0\\0&2&0\\0&0&1}$ and we will still have $$AU_1 = U_1D_1 $$

Comment: A couple of things went over my head, first how were you able to calculate the diagonal matrix D? That i the right matrix as it is in the textbook as well except for the 1 and 2 on each corner are interchanged. What do you mean by the order of the diagonal matrix?  I'm also hazy on your last part of the explanation

Comment: i thought the eigenvectors you listed corresponded to the eigenvalues one and two. i will add some more see it makes it easier to understand.